# ListView private broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, listactivity

I have private broadcast receiver inside of my Controller class. I am trying to have my Controller class listen for broadcast messages however i keep getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.android.five.Controller: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.five.Controller
```

Below is my setup.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "message recieved");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle.getString("ARTIST") != null) {

            String artist_name = bundle.getString("ARTIST");
            String track_name = bundle.getString("TRACK");
            Log.d(TAG, artist_name);
            Log.d(TAG, track_name);
        }
    }
};
```

This my manifest file.

```
<activity          
        android:name=".Controller"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.five.services.SONG_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.five.Controller" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.five.services.SONG_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Surely `<receiver android:name="com.android.five.Controller.BroadcastReceiver" >` ? But if its private don't think the manifest can see it, change it to public.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error; however, my controller class can does not listen for broadcast messages from my service.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest then it must be a class in its own right.  ie extend `BroadcastReceiver`.  Or you can register one with `registerReceiver`.

Comment: I already know how to do it this way. I want the list activity to listen for updates with a built in receiver.